# Defining a POST ajax call with KendoUI 2012 and VS 2012

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, kendo-ui

I'm new to Visual Studio and .net, so forgive me if I have some of the basics wrong.

This is what I wanna doe: fill content of a kendoui dropdownlist by using an ajax call. Now have I understood that it is preferred to use POST actions, but I cant get it to work.

Here's my code within the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeId)
      .DataTextField("Shortname")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetObjectTypes", "ObjectType")))
)
```

Here's my controller code:

```
[HttpPost] // use post to prevent 'leeching' 
public JsonResult GetObjectTypes()
{
    var objectTypes = _objecttypeRepository.All;
    return Json(objectTypes, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

The Ajax call doesn't gets to the GetObjectTypes at all.
If I remove the [HttpPost] and the "JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet" then this code works fine.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'GET' is actually the preferred method for retrieving resources (i.e. your dropdown list data), see [HTTP protocol request methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). 'POST' is normally used to submit data and creating a new resource.

I haven't done it myself, but if you really need to use 'POST' you may be able to specify it in the data source configuration, see kendo.data.DataSource's [transport.read.type](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportreadtype-string).

Answer (score 0):

When components like ComboBox/AutoComplete/Grid etc fetch their data they always use GET and there is no option to change it.